# Extracting only words from html pages

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and I have a folder with a list of html pages from which i would like to extract only the words from. Currently, the process that I am using is open the html file, run it through beautiful soup library, get the text and write it to a new file. But the problem here is I still get javascript, css (body, colour, #000000 .etc), symbols (|, `,~,[] .etc) and random numbers in the output.

How do I get rid of the unwanted output and get text only?

```
path = *folder path*
raw = open(path + "/raw.txt", "w")
files = os.listdir(path)
for name in files:
    fname = os.path.join(path, name)
    try:
        with open(fname) as f:
            b = f.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(b)
            txt = soup.body.getText().encode("UTF-8")
            raw.write(txt)
```

Comment: What do you mean by “word”? To extract words from a string, you need a very operative definition for “word”, one that can be turned into an algorithm. E.g., is “nit-picking” a word, or is it two words separated by a non-word character? What about “F1”, “i18n”, and “α”?

Comment: a word in this case is defined as anything that is available in the english dictionary

Comment: So you need a dictionary lookup then? (Using some dictionary that you regard as “the dictionary”.)

Comment: @user3702643, Perhaps I'm not understanding the question correctly. But are you just wanting to get all the text between tags on the page, except you don't want the text between script and style tags? If so, what's  wrong with the answer I provided? If that's not what you're looking for, you'll need to clarify.

Comment: sorry it actually worked perfectly. just forgot to reply you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could strip out the script and style tags

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.session()

soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684020/extracting-only-words- from-html-pages').text)

#This part here will strip out the script and style tags.
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
script.extract()

print soup.get_text()
```